# Does a manifold with zero simplicial volume necessarily admit a map $f$ with $|\deg f| > 1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

Let $\|M\|$ denote the [simplicial volume](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Simplicial_volume) of an oriented closed connected manifold.

If $f : M \to N$ is a continuous map between two oriented closed connected manifolds of the same dimension, then $|\deg f|\|N\| \leq \|M\|$. In particular, if $M$ admits a self-map $f$ with $|\deg f| > 1$, then $\|M\| = 0$. Is the converse true? I suspect that the answer is no, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample.

> Is there an oriented closed connected manifold $M$ with $\|M\| = 0$ but which does not admit a self-map $f$ with $|\deg f| > 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, if $M$ is a compact Nilmanifold, it has zero simplicial volume. On the other hand, there are nontrivial finitely-generated torsion-free co-hopfian nilpotent groups $\Gamma$ (see for instance [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0302220)). Taking $M$ a compact Nilmanifold with the fundamental group $\Gamma$ we obtain an example of a manifold with zero simplicial volume an no self-maps of degree $>1$. (Any such map would induce an epimorphism $\Gamma\to \Gamma'$, where $\Gamma'<\Gamma$ is a finite index subgroup. That would contradict the co-hopfian property of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Why do nilmanifolds have zero simplicial volume? Also, why does the existence of an epimorphism $\Gamma \to \Gamma'$ contradiction the co-hopfian property?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Compact manifolds with amenable fundamental groups have zero simplicial volume (this is in Gromov's 1982 paper). Each quotient of a f.g. nilpotent group $N$ by an infinite subgroup has strictly smaller rational cohomological dimension. Hence, it cannot be isomorphic to a finite index subgroup of $N$.

Comment: How can I see that the quotient of a finitely generated nilpotent group by an infinite subgroup has strictly smaller rational cohomological dimension? Also, is it clear why the kernel of $\Gamma \to \Gamma'$ would have to be infinite?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: For the second question: This group is torsion-free, hence, contains no nontrivial finite subgroups. For the first question, the key is that the cohomological dimension of a f.g. torsion-free nilpotent group $G$ is the dimension of its associated Lie algebra $L(G)$ and the latter is functorial: A homomorphism $\phi: G_1\to G_2$ induces a homomorphism $L(\phi): L(G_1)\to L(G_2)$. If $\phi$ is not injective, $L(\phi)$ is not injective either.